# Flutter Google Sign-In not working platformexception

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Google sign-in not working on real device (release mode) but working on emulator. I did all related settings like SHA-1 Keys, support email, enabled google authentications etc.

I am getting a strange error

> I/flutter ( 2385): PlatformException(sign_in_failed, g1.b: 10: , null,
> null)

Please help me with this. I am stuck with this almost 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

Got it guys. If app is not working in release mode you need to copy the SHA-1 Keys from Play store account to firebase.

[image]